search contain keywords in notpad++
I want to search for a description string that has a keyword. Examples are the current output.
  description xxxx
  policy-group APPS
  description yyyy
  policy-group APPS
  description zzzz
  policy-group APPS_1

If I want to search only the description that has policy-group APPS, how do I do it? Notice that the policy group is coming on the second line after the description, and I think the first search will be missed. How can we prevent that?
Thanks
A solution and the most accessible reg expression.

welcome to SO. We invite you to share the effort made thus far, which regex are you currently using? I personally feel this question is borderline: if we focus on regex, it has a place here. If not, then it's more suitable for SuperUser

"Sometimes, you may find yourself frustrated by the comments. Maybe they make suggestions that you have already tried should already have tried. Maybe they totally misunderstand your problem." (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  this is, one of the reasons, you should share what your tried.


Ctrl+F
Find what: ^description\h+\K.+?(?=policy-group APPS\b)
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
TICK . matches newline
Find All in Current Document

Explanation:
^                       # beginning of line
    description             # literally
    \h+                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    \K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
    .+?                     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    (?=                     # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
        policy-group APPS       # literally
        \b                      # word boundary
    )                       # end lookahead

Screenshot:

